# speed of nested synchronized

Tags: java, synchronized

Is a nested synchronized block faster to get into than a normal synchronized block? Or for example, which of the following routines is faster:

```
void routine1(SyncClass a) {
  a.syncMethod1();
  a.syncmethod2();
  a.syncMethod1();
}

void routine2(SyncClass a) {
  synchronized(a) {
    a.syncMethod1();
    a.syncmethod2();
    a.syncMethod1();
  }
}
```

The methods are synchronized. I am considering the use of a thread safe object in a situation where thread safety is not needed. So level of concurrency is not affected.

Also, is the answer platform dependant?

Comment: what you must consider is the correctness 1st when do the fine grained synchronization. As for the answer routine2 is faster unless the JVM coarsen the monitor and compiles routine1 the same way as routine2. There is no inherent benefit to lock/unlock unless there is some code in-between.

Comment: @bestsss Under what circumstances will the JVM coarsen the monitor and why and what precisely does that mean? And do you have a link to documentation?

Comment: monitor coarsening is a technique to avoid frequent monitor entering as it's not a free operation and requires a CAS. Google tends to yield pretty good results once you have the keywords (lock coarsen) - so the original java6 white paper: http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/6_performance.html#2.1.2

Comment: where coarsening is useful: `Vector v... for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++) {Object o = v.get(i); ...}` The operation requires 2xvector size lock acquisition+release - like I told it aint free, so it's wrapped into a single lock: synchronized(v){....} the effects will be the same. JMM explicitly allows lock/volatile coarsening. When possible biased locks can be used that avoids the expensive CAS but the results vary on the different CPU architectures - even between Nehalem and Sandy Bridge. *biased locking is covered in the same paper*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the answer is yes, as per comments left on the question. But with two caveats.

1) Due to fewer opportunities for parallel execution, threads may wait on each other more often.

2) The compiler may optimize this way automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off `synchronized`ing the smallest code elements you can, performance-wise, regardless of the platform.

Wrapping a number of synchronized calls in a `synchronized` block will reduce concurrency (and so, performance).  Only do it if you need that particular sequence of calls to be synchronized.

If you're concerned about the performance impact *besides* that which is derived from concurrency, I don't know which is faster.  However, I would expect that difference in performance in both of the methods you describe is imperceptible.

Comment: Can only reduce *concurrency*.

Comment: @EJP Subtle but valid!  Fixed.

Comment: keep in mind that JVM may coarsen the monitor if it sees fit. Obtaining the monitor is not free

Comment: could you clarify your language please? Does more atomically mean larger or smaller synchronized code blocks in context?

Comment: @warren I have amended my answer based on your revised question; hopefully it proves helpful.

Comment: *I would expect that difference in performance in both of the methods you describe is imperceptible.* - this is very very wrong. lock acquisition is CAS + owner set, lock release is a volatile write. Both operations are truly expensive and cause local CPU latency at least [speed degrade] and worse coherency traffic in non-100%-interconnected architectures. Look up *lock coarsening* and *biased locking* for extra info, also have a look at the white paper I linked in the question comments.

Comment: @bestsss I stand corrected!  You should add an answer of your own.  :)

Comment: wow, it's so rare anyone can admit being wrong on SO. hats off :) as a side note: locks prevent some more optimizations as well, namely out of order execution.